# Zurb Foundation strange gem issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, zurb-foundation

Working on a MacBook Pro, Zurb Foundation is acting funny. Dropdown menus don't work, Orbit slider acting funny, etc. I figure there's a problem in my code. But if I checkout the same exact project on 2 different computers (a windows 7 PC and another MacBook Pro), everything works perfect.

I checked every file difference and the only file that's different is the `assets/foundation_and_overrides.css` file.

This is the difference, the rails server that's not working properly shows these kinds of lines:

```
/* line 241, ../../../../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@ucode/gems/zurb-foundation-4.2.3/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss */
```

And the computers that work fine show something similar to:

```
/* line 264, ../../../../../../Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zurb-foundation-4.3.1/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss */
```

As you can see, the issue seems to be that the bad rails server is using an older version of Zurb Foundation for some reason. Even though `bundle update` shows version 4.3.1. In fact, we specified this in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'zurb-foundation', '4.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
bundle exec rails s
```

to make sure you're using the gems from the bundle, not system gems. Also it looks like you're using a different version of ruby. Are you using rvm or anything else to set the ruby version?

Comment: +1 on running `bundle exec rails s` this will be true of anything else you run, for example `bundle exec g foundation:install`. I know a lot of rails devs alias `bundle exec` to `be` to save some keystrokes. This is because once you use a specific version with bundler, rather than the latest version you must run prepend this command every time.

Comment: using `rvm` on the 2 MacBook Pros, just used rubyinstaller on the PC. The 2 MacBook Pros have exactly the same Ruby versions. I'll try the above